# how to display data in listview from database using raw query

Tags: android, listview

in my project there are 2 activities; in one Activity the user enters 2 symptoms and presses a button, which opens the next Activity. I want the next activity to display all names of possible diseases as per the symptoms, in listview format. Can anyone tell me how to do this? I had tried, but its showing nullpointer exception. I'm using a Sqlite database.

```
public class LstView extends Activity {
private Database db;
private Auto ato;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listname);
        ListView lstv =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        db=new Database(LstView.this);
        db.openDB();
        String a=ato.selected;
        String b=ato.selected1;
       // String[] lst=db.getName(a, b);
        String[] from=new String[]{db.COLUMN_1_NAME};
       int[] to= new int[]{R.id.text};
       Cursor csr=db.getName(a, b); 
      // ArrayAdapter<String> adt= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),R.layout.list_view,lst);
       SimpleCursorAdapter adt =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view, csr, from, to);
      // SimpleCursorAdapter adt = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, db.getName(a,b), new String[] { "Name" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
        lstv.setAdapter(adt);
 }


}
```

---

```
String[] Sympt= db.getSymptom();



    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_view,Sympt);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    textView.setThreshold(1);
    textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

             int    idn=arg0.getId();
              selected = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                System.out.println("newww "+idn);
                System.out.println("newww1 "+selected);
                String[] Sympt1=db.getSymptom1(selected);
                for(int i=0;i<Sympt1.length;i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("value array "+Sympt1[i]);
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_view,Sympt1);
                textView1.setAdapter(adapter1);
                textView1.setThreshold(1);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
textView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int idn1=arg0.getId();
        selected1=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
        System.out.println("neww2"+idn1);
        System.out.println("neww3"+selected1);

    }
});
search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LstView.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

});



}

here is the which im geting after clicking on button
```

03-16 09:49:33.993: W/dalvikvm(331): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.autocmplt/com.example.autocmplt.LstView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.example.autocmplt.LstView.onCreate(LstView.java:22)
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-16 09:49:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  ... 11 more
03-16 09:49:37.643: I/Process(331): Sending signal. PID: 331 SIG: 9

Comment: maybe some java code or logcat would be good...

Comment: post your log output here...

Answer (score 0):

What is Database? There's no android class for it, so if you're using SQLite then you're using something other than the version provided with the Android platform.

Anytime you get an exception, you *must* post a logCat. Most people following this list are pressed for time, so we can't spend an hour searching through your code to find things that *might* cause a problem. Conversely, a logCat immediately identifies the statement that's causing the error.

You should also consider adding comments to your code and giving more mnemonic names to your classes, methods, and variables. Reading code from scratch is hard to do anyway, and it gets worse when we have to look through the code to figure out what "a" is supposed to be.

Comment: i'm using "a" and "b" to store a data from autocompletetext and pass this data to database class to select Name from column and display it in Listviewview form